# Prevent invalid activation page failure

Tags: users, activation

I created a custom page for account activation failure and I'm telling Craft to route to my custom page by setting the general config setting **activateAccountFailurePath**. This works as expected.

What I'd like to do is prevent users from being able to directly navigate to the custom account activation failure page. I'd prefer this page only be displayed when Craft routes the user to it. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your config, you can set `activateAccountFailurePath` to something like:

`'activationAccountFailurePath' => 'members/failed?access=1'`

In your template, you can check for the URL parameter 'access' and 404 if it is not set.

Template:

```
{% if craft.request.getParam('access') != '1' %}
   {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

{# rest of your template if parameter is available #}
```

Of course, someone could still access the page if they had the full URL with the parameter, but it should help limit access.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that also. If this is the **only** viable option I guess that's what I'll do.